# QGIS raster image leaving original colors intact

Tags: qgis, raster, color

I'm using a program that generates a map using a set of colors (radio signal strength ranges, to be specific). It outputs the file as a jpg image with KML, so it displays perfectly well in Google Earth and in any photo viewer. But when I try to read it into QGIS (I've got 3.2 installed now), the raster processing functions seem to demand that they take over and replace the colors. Using palleted unique values, I was able to painstakingly regenerate something close to the original, but none of the options seem to just want to display the colors as the jpg file shows them.

Is there a trick I'm missing?

Comment: Add gdalinfo report about your jpg. Even better if you can share one for testing.

Comment: I'm not sure where the gdainfo report would be. I'm just learning QGIS; my usual GIS is MapInfo. That doesn't do fancy raster stuff, but once you register a picture it shows in its own colors.  QGIS does report this:
Width
1800
Height
1790
Data type
Byte - Eight bit unsigned integer
GDAL Driver Description
VRT
GDAL Driver Metadata
Virtual Raster
Dataset Description
D:\TEMP\Otelco\CBRS-allnodes.kml
Compression

Band 1
STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=113
STATISTICS_MEAN=10.414716561128
STATISTICS_MINIMUM=0
STATISTICS_STDDEV=5.6989374677964

Comment: Is there a setting that just displays jpg rasters without trying to interpret them?

Comment: Does your image really have just one band? Does the KML part contain the palette?

Comment: I assume it has one band, but I don't really understand how bands work -- RadioMobile produces the picture (can also be PNG -- that may work a bit better?) and every other program just displays it. The KML only contains the boundaries. I think there's a general issue here that QGIS is using raster palettes to encode information, not just display the presented colors, which I want.

Comment: A sample image would be appreciated. I have never seen QGIS to alter colors. As a test you could delete/rename the KML and open .jpg directly.

Comment: I tried one more. If I use .jpg as the image format, the colors seem to import correctly, but the usual jpeg artifacts occur -- the image is a bitmap picture, 1-5 arc seconds/pixel, and jpeg smears images. PNG is what drives QGIS nuts. The first .png I loaded actually changed its colors as I zoomed in and out, though never showing the originals. Deleting the KML, of course, loses the coordinates, and it is worthless if it doesn't register precisely.

Comment: Problem is certainly possible to solve if you could share some test data.